# How to make Tiller highly available?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I'm using [helm](https://helm.sh/) to deploy my services to a Kubernetes cluster.
I want to improve the service availability of my tiller pod. So I scaled the tiller deployment to 2 replicas.
Helm is working as before with no issues that might be related to this.

Does anyone have an idea why this might NOT be a good idea to increase reliability of helm and tiller?

**EDIT:**

- Helm v3 is expected to drop the usage of tiller. Making this issue not relevant
- If you want a tillerless experience in helm v2, you can use a [helm-tiller plugin](https://github.com/rimusz/helm-tiller)

Answer (score 5):

Running two tillers does not make it HA. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2334) at the moment.

Comment: Not true HA. But "Higher Availability" :-)